# How to use in HTML your ip address using $_SERVER in imgage

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

at the moment I'm setting up a Webserver which contains a live Stream from my Raspberry PI Camera. However, I use it at different places and I want my index.php knows automatically which IP he should use to open the camera. The cam will be open using my `ipAddress:8081/?action=stream.`

```
<img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>:8081/?action=stream" alt="Kamera" width = "640" height="480"
```

Here what it shows using $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
[image]

What it shows using my ip address instead of $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
[image]

Comment: Your image will load correctly, assuming it sits at `http://IP_ADDRESS:8081/?action=stream"`.

Comment: I added a few picture. There you can see if I use http://192.xxx.xxx.xx:8081/?action=stream, it works.